# Changing directories in a shell. Writing my own shell in C

Tags: c, shell, terminal

I am writing a simple shell in C. Right now when I run the command cd only work in the current environment that I am. So for example if I am in the Desktop folder I can only cd for a folder inside Desktop, I can't go to other folders in my computer.
How do I control this change of directories?

Thant's my cd function right now. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
int cmd_cd(char **args)
{
  if (args[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
  } else {
    if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, args[1],strerror(errno));;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Here is my exec function that calls cd

```
char* builtCommandList[] = {"cd", "exit"};
int builtinSize = sizeof(builtCommandList) / sizeof(char *);

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &cmd_cd,
  &cmd_exit
};

int execute(char **args){


      if(args[0] == NULL)
          return 1;


        for(int i =0; i<builtinSize;i++){
            if (strcmp(args[0], builtCommandList[i]) == 0) {
                printf("function is here");
                return (*builtin_func[i])(args);

                }


            }

        pid_t pid, wpid;
          int status;

          pid = fork();
          if (pid == 0) {
            // Child process
            if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error in child process");
            }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          } else if (pid < 0) {
            // Error forking
            fprintf(stderr, "error forking");
          } else {
            // Parent process
            do {
              wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
            } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
          }

          return 1;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you `cd ..` or `cd /`?

Comment: The `chdir()` system call works with relative or absolute paths.  If it is failing, look hard at the string you pass to it.  Do not include a newline at the end, for example.

Comment: @rslemos if I do cd .. it goes back to the previous directory. So if I am at Desktop and do cd newFolder, then after at newFolder I do cd ... I go back to Desktop. And just checked that cd / takes me back to the beginning of my configuration like users and stuff. Then from there I can keep going folder per folder. But I still can't do ~/Documents

Comment: Please edit the question to include a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Before executing a command, it's a great idea to print out exactly what you're going to execute. This may well show you what the problem is. That's about as much help as we can offer, I think, unless you post a reproducible example here

Comment: @p20xx So your `cd` implementation is working fine. What you need is command line interpretation. See, expanding `~`  to `$HOME` (or `~a` to a's home) is something the your shell must do manually. The kernel won't do it for you.

Comment: @p20xx Usually a complete shell will do many other stuff, like file redirection (see bash `>>`, `>&`, `<<`), command line expansion (enviroment variables and alike), job handling (session leaders, tty controlling and so on), signal handling (`SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`)... It is hard to make a fully fledged shell.

Comment: @rslemos can you explain it a little further? I am very new with Kernel. So how can I make my code understand that I want to do ~/Documents for example?

Comment: @p20xx You'll have to take the input string (perhaps `args[.]` or even better, the full string right off `fgets` or [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)) and rewrite it, expanding `~` to be your `$HOME` directory. `chdir` - a system call (i.e. it is implemented inside the kernel) - won't do it for you.

Comment: Tilde expansion is made by the shell itself, it's not something that is inherent in POSIX path resolution.